# Not possible to use Realm in an iOS Messages extension?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Just to be clear, its currently not possible to use Realm to have a single shared database between an iOS app and a Messages extension?

Comment: It's possible, as long as your database doesn't need to use the Realm Object Server synchronization functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It is very much possible

For **Swift 3**

I used the following code to share Realm db between app and app extension:

```
let sharedDirectory: URL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.your.app")! as URL
let sharedRealmURL = sharedDirectory.appendingPathComponent("db.realm")
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: sharedRealmURL)
```

Just call this code from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` of `AppDelegate` and `viewDidLoad` of `MSMessagesAppViewController`